# Dojo publish - subscribe not working

Tags: javascript, dojo, event-handling, publish, publish-subscribe

The code below is a simple abstraction of what I want to do - it deals with publish and subscribe of the dojo event model. My aim is to publish an event, and subscribe a method to that event.

```
<html> 
<head>
<script> 
dojoConfig={async:true, parseOnLoad: true}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/topic","dojo/domReady!"],

    function(topic){

    function somethod() {
        alert("hello;");
    }
    try{
        topic.publish("myEvent");
    }
    catch(e){
        alert("error"+e);
    }

    //topic.publish("myEvent");  
try{
topic.subscribe("myEvent", somethod);

}catch(e){alert("error in subscribe"+e);}
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

I get no alerts, not even in try and catch blocks. Developer console also shows no errors. Is this the correct way to handle publish and subscribe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close but have made one little mistake. You're subscribing to the topic *after* you're publishing to it, so you're not catching it. If you put the pub after the sub it'll work.

Here's your sample with slight modifications and comments:

```
<html> 
<head>
<script> 
dojoConfig={async:true, parseOnLoad: true}
</script>
<!-- I used the CDN for testing, but your local copy should work, too -->
<script data-dojo-config="async: 1"
        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js">
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
require(["dojo/topic","dojo/domReady!"],
function(topic){

    function somethod() {
        alert("hello;");
    }
    try{
        topic.publish("myEvent");
        /* ignored because no one is subscribed yet */
    }
    catch(e){
        alert("error"+e);
    }

    try{
        topic.subscribe("myEvent", somethod);
        /* now we're subscribed */

        topic.publish("myEvent");
        /* this one gets through because the subscription is now active*/

    }catch(e){
        alert("error in subscribe"+e);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```